# Mapping each row of database to each row of listview

Tags: android, mysql, android-widget, android-listview

I want to amp each database to each row of listview...
Actually my prob is i amm able to fetch data from database but its not displaying in list view prperly 
my code is:

```
try
    {           
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/meetingschedular/fetchmeet.php?uid="+vwname.getText().toString());
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();   
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        //Convert response to string
        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");

                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();                 
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        //END Convert response to string

            try
            {               
                JSONArray jArray =  new JSONArray(result);

                    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
                    {   
                        JSONArray innerJsonArray = jArray.getJSONArray(i);
                        JSONObject json_data = innerJsonArray.getJSONObject(0);                          
                        String at1=json_data.getString("title");
                        String at= json_data.getString("mdate");
                        String at2=json_data.getString("mtime");
                        String at3=json_data.getString("venue");
                        String at4=json_data.getString("organiser");
                        s.append("\nTitle:"+at1);
                        s.append("\ndate:"+at);
                        s.append("\nTime:"+at2);
                        s.append("\nVenue:"+at3);
                        s.append("\nOrganiser:"+at4);                       
                        r.add(s.toString());                            
                    }

                l.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, r));}
```

Its displaying like this

[image: Listview]

I want to display each row seperately. All the rows are being display in a single row . Pls Hlp me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
s = new StringBuilder();
```

in the start of for loop

Comment: i have done it but no use, all the rows of database is getting displayed in single listview row.

Comment: EDIT change the `sb` to `s`. Try to use good naming for your variables. Your current code is appending `s` every time the loop runs, so you need to re-initialize your variable `s`. if you have changed anything in your code, please update the question

Answer (score 0):

try to add this line in your listview: (It may be possible you can not see the divider in the listview)

```
android:divider="#000000"
android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
```